# VMware PowerShell scripting - automated gmail

Tags: powershell, vmware

This works, but...

```
$EmailFrom = "vsphere@nasa.gov"
$EmailTo = "userwithOLDsnapshot@nasa.gov" 
$Subject = "Notification" 
$Body = "this is a notification for your snapshot"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Is there anyway of doing this with a credential store?  Embedding creds in scripts in clear text is a no no.

Comment: If it's not important that this goes right to GMail it might be better to run SMTP locally (locked down of course) or use an internal SMTP server that doesn't require authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create an encrypted string. You can save this output to some file and read it in later:
`$securePWord=Read-Host "Enter some password" -AsSecureString`

This will convert a SecureString into usable text:
`$pWord=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securePWord))`